# Procrustes analysis / Finding the Angle Between two images represented by two sets of 2d points

Tags: algorithm, image, math, image-processing, image-manipulation

If I have 2 sets of points I can rotate one around with [Procrustes analysis](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.119.2686&rep=rep1&type=pdf) to align one with the other.

But suppose these 2 sets of points each are attached to images and I would like to rotate the images as well. Is there any way I can also rotate the image, instead of rotating just the points? The tutorial there uses a dot product for rotation (solve `u, s, v = svd(p1', p2)` and then do `p2 . v . u'`, p' is transposed p)

However that doesn't tell me what the angle between the images is.

[The page on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procrustes_analysis) calculates an angle between each pair of points I think.

Maybe what I'm asking is impossible? If I rotate the first set of points to align it with the first, can't I also rotate the respective images by an angle as well? Point being, which angle is that?

I noticed that `v . u'` gives me a 2 x 2 matrix which seems to be the rotation matrix (there's a wikipedia page but I can't link there due to posting priviledges). I got the sin and cos of the third and first elements and then used arctan2, but the results I'm getting are kind of weird. I know they have to be transformed from radians but I'm not convinced what I'm doing is right. Trying the rotation it gives me on gimp makes it seem like it's not what I want, but I'll test some more.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your approach is mostly correct. Two things which come to mind:

1) The paper you linked to (Procrustes analysis) involves a translation and a scaling in addition to rotation. Depending on whether or not those operations are also performed on your images, you may end up with strange results that don't appear to match.

2) I think you may be overcomplicating your angle calculation. v * u' appears to be the correct rotation matrix, but I believe the correct angle only requires one of the matrix entries in the 2x2 matrix. For instance, just use acos() of the first matrix entry. As you've noticed, this will (depending on the program) give you an answer in radians which you'll have to convert to degrees if you want to try out the rotation in gimp, etc.

Hope this helps!

Comment: i think atan2/arctan2 is better because it tells me the angle with the correct quadrant.

Comment: That's fine, but my point is that you don't take the cos or sin OF the first and third elements and THEN use atan. If you want the correct quadrant, take the atan2 of Q(2,1) / Q(1,1) where Q is the rotation matrix and the numbers in brackets indicate the row and column respectively. Just take the matrix values directly.